# Type mismatch with Single type of data

Tags: vba, excel

I need to use `Single` type of data but I have an error if I enter `.` or `-`: Type mismatch

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Call inputPotential(TextBox1.Value)
End Sub
Private Function inputPotential(ByRef inputValueSingle As Single)
End Function
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Call inputPotential(TextBox1.Value)
```

to

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then Call inputPotential(TextBox1.Value)
```

having only a `-` or `.` isnt a single-type number -> counts as string :)